# How to select rows between two different columns with two different input values on same table on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table name as Orders. Orders table have two columns names are start_date,end_date

```
S.No     start_date   end_date
 1       2016-04-01   2016-04-08
 2       2016-04-28   2016-05-29
 3       2016-05-01   2016-05-39
```

Now I want records between start date of 2016-04-01 and end date of 2016-04-30.

Please help me on this

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want records that overlap the range:

```
SELECT *
  FROM orders
 WHERE start_date <= :end_range
   AND end_date   >= :start_range
```

In your case:

```
SELECT *
  FROM orders
 WHERE start_date <= '2016-04-30'
   AND end_date   >= '2016-04-01'
```

This works as below:

```
           <---RANGE-->
     <-->                                     X end_date   < :start_range
R      <---->                                 Returned
O             <---->                          Returned
W         <--------------->                   Returned
S                   <---->                    Returned
                            <-->              X start_date > :end_range
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `start_date` is always <= `end_date`, you may get better results with the query below, as it gives more specificity on the `start_date` filter:

```
select * 
from Orders 
where start_date between '2016-04-01' and '2016-04-30'
    and end_date between '2016-04-01' and '2016-04-30'
```

Comment: It will return first row only. But I want 2nd row also. because 2ndd row start date is less than filter range

Answer (score 1):

Do you want: 
select * from orders where start_date between '04/01/2016' AND '04/30/2016'
AND end_date between '04/01/2016' AND '04/30/2016'

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
select * 
from Orders 
where 
    (start_date >= '2016-04-01' and start_date < '2016-05-01');
```

**Edit**
Update to reflect comments from OP.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1553c/2)

Comment: No Mituw. I have two date filters of start date and end date. If I select start date filter as 2016-04-05 and end date filter as 2016-04-30 then both records should come because 2nd row start date is less than filter end date

Comment: I see, I will edit my answer accordingly and update the fiddle.

Comment: Saw that its not correct. If record have start date of 05 then it is also coming.

Comment: @mallip You need to clearly explain what you're asking then. As you can tell by the face there are 3 very different answer trying to accomplish roughly the same task, we are guessing as to what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Sorry for you trouble.  I want records between start date of 2016-04-01 and end date of 2016-04-30.

Comment: so you want this then? `start_date >= '2016-04-01' or end_date <= '2016-04-30'; ` ?

Comment: No. Ur query will return 3rd row also but I want only between 04-01 to 04-30

Comment: I am still very confused by the wording of your question, but is this what you're after? @mallip .. edits in answer

Comment: But it will not return 2nd row.

Comment: I give up.. I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish. The above query **cleary** returns row 2 of the sample data. Did you even click on the SQL fiddle?

Comment: @mituw16 Pretty sure he wants records that overlap the range.. see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only orders that ran from 4/1 - 4/30 then:

```
SELECT *
FROM
   orders
WHERE
   start_date = '2016-4-1'
   AND end_date = '2016-4-30'
```

If you want orders that *either* started on 4/1 OR ended on 4/30 then:

```
SELECT *
FROM
   orders
WHERE
   start_date = '2016-4-1'
   OR end_date = '2016-4-30'
```

**Edit after OP comment**

```
SELECT *
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    start_date between '2016-4-1' AND '2016-4-30'
    OR end_date between '2016-4-1' AND '2016-4-30'
```

Comment: I ran this query but no records are showing. I want between records not exact matching records

Comment: Cool, check out between